# Bike Gear Indicator Coding Problem

Tags: programming, arduino-nano, sketch

Lack of practice I forgot many function of C & C++...
Can anyone help me with this coding Please...

I think this is The Main coding:
[Topic: Gear indicator](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=103620.0;wap)

I first found this, [Gear_Indicator_Raw](https://github.com/BlueAG/Gear-1/blob/master/Gear_Indicator_Raw/Gear_Indicator_Raw.ino)

**But, There was many problem in those sketch,**

1. Those sketches work just like simple counter,
2. Can't Show "2" from "0"
3. No Neutral Detection,

As Bike Gear, (1 N 2 3 4 5) One Down Four up, I made some Changes,
But can't add the Neutral part smoothly...

And here, My code:

```
#define BUTTON_DOWN 13
#define BUTTON_UP 4
#define BUTTON_N 11

int ledPinA = 7;
int ledPinB = 12;
int ledPinC = 10;
int ledPinD = 9;
int ledPinE = 8;
int ledPinF = 6;
int ledPinG = 5;

int val_up = 0;
int val_down = 0;
int val_n = 0;
int old_val_n = 0;
int old_val_down = 0;
int old_val_up = 0;
int gear = 0;
// The setup() method runs once, when the sketch starts

void setup()
{
  pinMode(BUTTON_N, INPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON_UP, INPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON_DOWN, INPUT);

  pinMode(ledPinA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinF, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinG, OUTPUT);
}

void led0()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPinA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinC, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinD, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinE, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinF, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinG, HIGH);
}
void led1()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPinA, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinC, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinD, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinE, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinF, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinG, HIGH);
}
void led2()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPinA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinC, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinD, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinE, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinF, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinG, LOW);
}
void led3()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPinA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinC, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinD, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinE, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinF, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinG, LOW);
}
void led4()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPinA, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinC, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinD, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinE, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinF, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinG, LOW);
}
void led5()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPinA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinB, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinC, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinD, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinE, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinF, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinG, LOW);
}
void led6()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPinA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinB, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinC, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinD, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinE, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinF, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinG, LOW);
}
void led7()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPinA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinC, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinD, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinE, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinF, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinG, HIGH);
}
void led8()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPinA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinC, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinD, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinE, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinF, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinG, LOW);
}
void led9()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPinA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinC, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinD, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinE, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinF, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPinG, LOW);
}

void setLed(int number)
{
  switch (number)
  {
    case 0:  
      led0();
      break;
    case 1:  
      led1();
      break;
    case 2:  
      led2();
      break;
    case 3:  
      led3();
      break;
    case 4:  
      led4();
      break;
    case 5:  
      led5();
      break;
    case 6:  
      led6();
      break;
    case 7:  
      led7();
      break;
    case 8:  
      led8();
      break;
    case 9:  
      led9();
      break;
  }
}

// the loop() method runs over and over again,
// as long as the Arduino has power

void oldloop()
{
  led0();
  led1();
  led2();
  led3();
  led4();
  led5();
  led6();
  led7();
  led8();
  led9();
}

void loop()
{
//neutral

    val_n =  digitalRead(BUTTON_N);
    if ((val_n == HIGH) &&gear<=2)
    {
      gear = 0;                         //Posted wrong "gear = HIGH"
      delay(100);
    }

// Gear Up

    val_up = digitalRead(BUTTON_UP);
    if ((val_up == HIGH) && (old_val_up == LOW) &&(gear<6) && (gear>0))
    {
      gear += 1;
      delay(100);
    }

    else if ((val_up == HIGH) && (old_val_up == LOW) &&(gear==0))
    {
      gear += 2;
      delay(100);
    }
    old_val_up = val_up;

// Gear Down

    val_down = digitalRead(BUTTON_DOWN);
    if ((val_down == HIGH) && (old_val_down == LOW)&& (gear>1))
    {
      gear -= 1;
      delay(100);
    }

    else   if ((val_down == HIGH) && (old_val_down == LOW) && (gear==0))
    {
      gear += 1;
      delay(100);
    }
    old_val_down = val_down;

// Max Limit

    if (gear >= 5)
    {
      gear = 5;
    }

    setLed(gear);
}
```

**The Problem:**

1. Without the "// neutral" part it's work OK, but can't show "0" without reset.
2. With the "// neutral" part, While **gear up**, instead of increasing, display shows "0" after "1".
3. If I press pin "4" very quickly, then it's increasing to Max gear.

I think there is some problem in this part:

```
//neutral

    val_n =  digitalRead(BUTTON_N);
    if ((val_n == HIGH) &&gear<=2)
    {
     gear = HIGH;
      delay(100);
    }
```

And, Please, If anyone can tell me about "Void oldloop()", what this is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Likely problem**

I'm not sure how to solve the problem, however, I see at least one item that looks strange in the //neutral part:

```
gear = HIGH;
```

This seems `gear` is a pin status (LOW/HIGH), but two lines above:

```
if ((val_n == HIGH) &&gear<=2)
```

Here `gear` is an integer value. This seems quite inconsequent to me.

**Pin 4**

The reason is you do not have a debouncing algorithm, check for a Debounce Arduino example. When a button is pressed or depressed, it switches sometimes very fast a few times; this might result in multiple increases/decreases of the gear.

**oldLoop**

The function `oldLoop` is not used, but if you swap the names of `loop` and `oldLoop` you can use the 'test' scenario which is contained in `oldLoop`.

**Some other tips**

- Use spacing consequently
- You can refactor the LED code a lot.
- You can use `gear++;`  to increase or `gear--;` to decrease.

**Update**

(Changed debouncing problem for pin 4).

You changed in your neutral code:

```
gear = 0;
```

Shouldn't that be `gear = 1;`? As gear 1 means Neutral (gear 0 is 1).

Comment: Oops, sorry, I actually I used "gear=0", But maybe It's a mistake while I was editing it to post here..!!!

Comment: Thanks, I shorted the code, as you said, the oldloop is useless, gear++ & gear-- working smoothly... But the neutral function still interrupting with gear up...

Comment: Than change the last line from `setLed(gear)` to `setLed(gear == 1 ? 0 : gear)` ... at least that's the simplest solution for the code you have now.

Comment: No, That does not works for me... But I guess I worked it out with ```if ((val_up == HIGH) && (val_n == LOW) && (gear>0))```... The "oldloop" was confusing me... Let me check couple of times...

Comment: All working very good, Also thanks about the debouncing part... It helps... But one last thing... How to ignore "hold" button... Holding the button/sensor little more It keeps increasing/decreasing to max limit... I want the output, **only after releasing the button**...

Comment: You can prevent holding a button when only triggering for a falling edge (i.e. depressing a button), or a rising edge (i.e. pressing a button)... the debounce algorithm will make sure you only have one edge.

Comment: kay, after hours I was testing the circuit...The problem raises again...!!! Also change the whole pin set up, then the gear-up running it's own... I think there is issue on pin sensitivity...!! (checked with other boards) Maybe I should use some pull-up resistors...Or use analog pins for Input,,,

Comment: No digital pins are ok, but you should indeed use pull-up or pull-down resistors in case the button is depressed.

Comment: Yes, I used 10k pull-down... It's working now... Let me check my final & actual project, so I can mark this as solved... :)

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Comment: Glad it's working!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are confused about the meaning of `gear`.

One possible meaning could be 0 = neutral, 1 .. 5 = gear. But then, when changing gears you can't simply do + or -,  as the sequence is 1 - 0 - 2 - 3 - ...

The other interpretation is:  gear-- from 2  means neutral and you display something that indicates neutral ( e.g. a '0' or a '-' ) whenever gear==1, and you display a '1' when you do another gear--, and have a numeric value of 0 in `gear`.

Your decision.

Comment: Actually I was confused about the "oldloop" part, and the original code was very complicated... I kind of shorted it... I think for the 7-segment, it could be done more simple...

Comment: Easiest is to change your  `switch (number) {   case 0: led1(); break;
    case 1:  ledneutral(); break;`

Comment: All I understand after lots of failing... That, the problem is with Arduino pins sensitivity...!!! -_-  There should be a full list of all common problems..!!!